# OSX SPHP switch PHP version without reboot?

Tags: macos, php

I installed the script [sphp](https://gist.github.com/rhukster/f4c04f1bf59e0b74e335ee5d186a98e2) to switch my brew php installation on OSX.

I am not sure if this is normal but even with the script executing correctly I have to reboot in order for the new version of PHP to be effective... The tutorial I followed did not mention any reboot.

Is this normal ? Is there a way to change PHP versions on OSX without any reboot ?

Comment: I'm sorry this problem seems super trivial to solve. Why exactly can't you reboot your computer?

Comment: @Anaksunaman; I am not using php via apache.

Comment: @Sickest rebooting is annoying when you have many windows/projects open and quickly want to switch between them easily

Comment: I suggest you look into using virtual OS then. Might solve this issue.

Answer (score 0):

actually it was probably a bug; I managed to switch without reboot this time; not sure why but it seems to be working now